# Getting pandas.read_html( ) to work when HTML table contains more than one <tbody> tag

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to parse the tables found at http://www.swiftcodesbic.com and I'm using `Pandas` to grab the tables automatically. For the most part, this is working fine, but there is one table where there are two `<tbody>` tags and I think it's causing a hiccup. The faulty table can be found [here](http://www.swiftcodesbic.com/france/).

The code I'm using to parse the html into a `pandas.DataFrame` is:

`pandas.read_html(countryPage.text, attrs={"id":"t2"}, skiprows=1)[0]`

where `countryPage` is a `requests.get()` object. Is there anything I can add to the pandas call to tell it to grab the second `<tbody>` tag? Or, if that's not the issue, can someone explain what might be causing it return a "table not found" error? Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***

Here's the solution I'm currently using, but I'd still like to know a more 'pythonic' approach to this.

```
try:
  tempDataFrame = pd.read_html(countryPage.text, attrs={"id":"t2"}, skiprows=1)[0]
except:
  if "france" is in url: #pseudo-code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(countryPage.text)
    table = soup.find_all("table")[2].findAll('tbody')[1] #this will vary based on your situation
    table = "<table>" + str(table) + "</table>" #pandas needs the table tag to recognize a table
    tempDataFrame = pd.read_html(table)[0]
```

Again, I'd be interested in knowing how to do this in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `match` parameter should do the trick. From pandas.read_html documentation:

```
match : str or compiled regular expression, optional

    The set of tables containing text matching this regex or string will be returned. Unless the HTML is extremely simple you will probably need to pass a non-empty string here. Defaults to ‘.+’ (match any non-empty string). The default value will return all tables contained on a page. This value is converted to a regular expression so that there is consistent behavior between Beautiful Soup and lxml.
```

Try something of this sort

```
tempDataFrame = pd.read_html(countryPage.text, match='foo', skiprows=1)
```

where foo is a string contained in the table